# Block incoming port

Tags: networking, iptables

I installed LabView on a Scientific Linux 6 machine and promptly got a message from our security officer, stating that the port 3580 is open and listening and that this is a security issue. Apparently, the port is used for [web monitoring and configuration server](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/12402/en/#toc2) and cannot be closed. Though, maybe I'm misunderstanding things, but if not: #%&!*#@

To see the listening port, I type

```
$ netstat -anp | grep 3580
> (Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
>  will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
> tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3580                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -
```

Now I tried to close the port using `iptables`:

```
$ iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 3580 -j DROP
```

But when I type the `netstat` command from above again, I still see the open port. Surely I'm just misunderstanding how `iptables` works. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: In the off chance that their scanner reports 'drop's as "open" you could change -j DROP to -j REJECT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

netstat shows you that something (probably Labview) is listening on that port. Your iptables line will block packets from outside the computer arriving at that port, and so there should be no problem. The program is listening, so you see that the port is open when executing netstat, but packets cannot arrive from outside, and so one cannot access the port from the outside. If you need to block packets from the computer itself it is possible but you may very well impact LabView functionality.

Notes:

- it is still possible for someone to detect your firewall rule, since I suppose that there are no other firewall rules. `iptables -L -n -v` to see them. You want to use DROP or REJECT according to the other rules. If the packet would be accepted, use REJECT, which will mimic a port that no program is listening on. EDIT: for a connection to a TCP port there are four possible results:

  1. the connection opens with a TCP SYN/ACK packet, which happens if there is  a program listening on the port and the connection is not blocked by a firewall
  2. the connection is rejected/reset with a TCP RST packet, which happens if there is no program listening on the port or if a firewall returns the RST (which iptables does with -j REJECT)
  3. no packet is returned at all, which happens if a packet is lost or if a firewall drops the packet (which iptables does with -j DROP)
  4. no TCP packet is returned but a firewall can return an ICMP packet, which is less common.

  So, from the outside of your machine your security officer can easily  detect the difference between TCP RST and no packet at all. If there is no firewall other than the one line, I would recommend using `-j REJECT` instead of `-j DROP` so that there is no difference from the other ports and so that the network scanner he is using does not hang for several irritating seconds while testing the port, instead getting an immediate RST saying "this port is closed" like he got for all the others. For an Internet-connected server I would recommend using `-j DROP` to make port scanning as time-consuming as possible for the bad guys, but your situation seems very different!
- The iptables line you gave will disappear on reboot. You need to either modify `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` by hand or else execute `/sbin/service iptables save` when your configuration is OK.
- Your iptables line will block the packets your security officer indicated, but you should investigate configuration where you only permit what you need and forbid everything else, with stateful configuration. LabView or another program could perfectly well open other ports. That subject is bit too large for this short an answer!
- You already know it's Labview, but seeing your netstat command I'd like to note that I prefer `lsof` (example `lsof -i :3580`, but it may not be installed) to see what is listening on a port. Most importantly it will tell you what program is listening, and then you can decide what to do with it. As with netstat you have to be root or use sudo in order to see everything (you have to be root to execute iptables also so I assume that is not a problem).

Comment: Thanks, this is a very comprehensive answer. Did I understand correctly, that the security officer will still see the port as open and hence may not acknowledge my solution?

Comment: not quite; edited answer to clarify